# Bounding coefficients of the polynomial $(1-x^2)^n (1-x)^{-m}$.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, approximation, upper-lower-bounds, rational-functions, negative-binomial

I have been trying to get some upper bound on the coefficient of $x^k$ in the polynomial
$$(1-x^2)^n (1-x)^{-m}, \text{ $m \le n$}.$$

A straightforward calculation shows that for even $k$, the coefficient can be expressed as
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k/2} (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} (-1)^{k-2i} \binom{-m}{k-2i} =  \sum_{i=0}^{k/2} (-1)^i\binom{n}{i} \binom{m+k-2i-1}{k-2i}$$
and therefore simply using $\binom{n}{k} \le n^{k}$, one gets a bound of
$$(k/2+1) (n+(m+k)^2)^{\frac{k}{2}} .$$

I'm wondering if one could get a better bound, ideally with a better dependence on $k$?

Comment: You can rewrite that as $(1-x)^p(1+x)^n$ where $n\geq p=n-m\geq0.$ Not sure how that helps, though.

Answer (score 1):

$(1-X^2)^n(1-X)^{-m}=(1+X)^n(1-X)^{n-m}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n-m}a_kX^k$ where
$$ a_k=\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i\binom{n-m}{i}\binom{n}{k-i} $$
Using $\binom{n}{k}\leqslant\frac{n^k}{k!}$, we have
$$ |a_k|\leqslant\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{(n-m)^i}{i!}\frac{n^{k-i}}{(k-i)!}\leqslant n^k\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{1}{i!(k-i)!}=\frac{(2n)^k}{k!} $$

Comment: Thanks.  I don't quite follow your lower bound.  When $m=0$ and $k$ is even, the coefficient of $x^k$ is $\binom{n}{k/2}$, which seems to contradict what you wrote?

Comment: Yeah, the lower bound is problematic.

Comment: In particular, if $m=0$ then your lower bound would mean $a_k=\frac{(2n)^k}{k!}.$. But when $m=0,$ $a_k=0$ when $k$ is odd.

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit too fast, I used $\binom{n}{k}\geqslant\frac{n^k}{k!}$ which is completely wrong, thank for pointing it out !

Answer (score 1):

One can get a better bound of
$$\frac{2^k}{(k/2)!} \bigl(n + (m+k)^2\bigr)^{k/2} .$$

Using $\binom{n}{k} \le n^k/k!\,$, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{k/2} (-1)^i\binom{n}{i} \binom{m+k-2i-1}{k-2i}
&\le \sum_{i=0}^{k/2} \frac{n^i}{i!} \frac{(m+k-2i-1)^{k-2i}}{(k-2i)!} \\
&\le (n + (m+k)^2)^{k} \sum_{i=0}^{k/2} \frac{1}{i! (k-2i)!} .
\end{align}
Following @Tuvasbien's argument, the summation can be bounded by
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{k/2} \frac{1}{i! (k-2i)!}
&=\sum_{i=0}^{k/2} \frac{(2i)!}{i!k!} \frac{k!}{(2i)! (k-2i)!} \\
&\le \frac{1}{(k/2)!}\sum_{i=0}^{k/2} \frac{k!}{(2i)! (k-2i)!} \\
&\le \frac{2^k}{(k/2)!} .
\end{align}